# Придаточное уступки или условия?

Tags: синтаксис

"Он сказал, что не выдаст меня, **даже если его станут пытать на пыточных станках инквизиции**."

Выделенная часть предложения - это придаточное уступки или условия?

Comment: господин Дёмин, можно спросить: почему Вы корректируете тексты сообщений? если автор вопроса считает нужным поздороваться с другими пользователями и заранее поблагодарить их за ответы, почему Вы вычёркиваете это? без обид, просто любопытство новичка...

Comment: Потому что это не относится к вопросу и создаёт "шум", который усложнит будущим посетителям чтение вопросов и ответов. Важно понимать, что сайты сети StackExchange - это своеобразная база знаний в формате "вопрос - ответ", а не чат или форум.

Answer (score 4):

"Он сказал, что не выдаст меня, **даже если** его станут пытать на пыточных станках инквизиции."

Это предложение интересно тем, что комплекс ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ имеет значение ирреальной (предположительной) уступки (пусть его пытают, несмотря на любые пытки).

Таким образом, форма предложения соответствует придаточному условному, а значение ближе к придаточному уступки.

Comment: ... спасибо Вам, Серж и Vera, большое! поняла! у меня сейчас ещё тогда один вопрос: 

"Но покупать и держать в доме сторожевого пса – привитого или не привитого, вольного или на цепи – отказался наотрез, хоть бы воры обобрали его до нитки." 

"хоть бы воры обобрали его до нитки" - если я эту часть переформулирую, то получится "даже если бы воры обобрали его до нитки" , ведь так? это получается тогда тоже придаточное условное? как можно тогда объяснить использование "хоть"? это какая-то экспрессивная частица?

Comment: В "Синтаксисе современного русского языка" Кустовой разбираются такие предложения, например: Мы закончим работу, хотя бы нам пришлось работать до утра. Это предложение относится к УСТУПИТЕЛЬНЫМ (но рассматривается в разделе "Частные грамматические значения"). Там же сказано: подобные отношения можно выразить комплексом "даже если".

Answer (score 3):

> "Он сказал, что не выдаст меня, **даже если его станут пытать на
>   пыточных станках инквизиции.**"

Наверное, наиболее правильным было бы назвать придаточное в этом предложении  ***уступительным*** (или ***условно-уступительным***).

У Черемисиной и др. в "Очерках по теории сложного предложения" ("Наука", 1987) говорится, что в русском вхождение частицы ***даже*** в конструкцию с союзом ***если*** переводит подобные конструкции в разряд ***уступительных (условно-уступительных)***.

К предложениям, выражающим уступительные отношения, относит предложения с ***даже если*** и  **["Русская грамматика"](http://rusgram.narod.ru/3043-3057.html)**:

> **ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ, ВЫРАЖАЮЩИЕ УСТУПИТЕЛЬНЫЕ ОТНОШЕНИЯ**
>
> **§ 3043.** В предложениях, выражающих уступительные отношения, соотносятся две ситуации, из которых одна, представленная в
>   придаточной части, не является достаточным основанием для того, чтобы
>   отменить собою другую, представленную в главной части.
>
> **§ 3048.** Эквивалентом уступительного союза может быть союз ***если*** - в тех случаях, когда его условно-гипотетическое значение ослабляется частицами ***и, даже, даже и*** в придаточной части.
>   Позиция частицы в составе придаточного строго не закреплена. Сближение
>   конструкций с ***если и, если даже*** с уступительными конструкциями
>   происходит при посредстве элемента допущения, вносимого в предложение
>   этими частицами.
>
> *Всякое обвинение, **даже если** оно высказывается в дамском обществе, должно быть формулировано с возможной определенностью, иначе оно не
>   обвинение, а пустое злословие, недостойное порядочных людей*.

Comment: если для Вас не трудно, не могли бы Вы помочь мне пожалуйста? Вы дали хороший ответ и поэтому я к Вам еще раз обращаюсь. здесь http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430075/x%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-vs-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8 мне сказали что через "даже если бы" можно выражать уступку + Вы подтвердили наверху. Я вернулась к своему старому вопросу и сомневаюсь, условное это предложение или нет? Разве нельзя это рассматривать как уступительное? = "Он бы ей всё равно не поверил, даже если бы это было правдой"? сеичас добавлю линк старого вопроса

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424066/%D0%9E%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем примере придаточное условие. Здесь союз "если", который всегда вводит придаточное условное.

Придаточные уступки прикрепляются к главному предложению при помощи:

> союзов: хотя, несмотря на то что, невзирая на то что, пускай (в значении «хотя»), пусть (в значении «хотя»), даром что (в значении «хотя») и др.;
>       союзных слов: как, сколько, что, где, куда, кто и др. – с обязательной частицей ни