# Он бы ей всё равно не поверил, даже будь это правдой.

Tags: синтаксис

*Он бы ей всё равно не поверил, **даже будь это правдой**.*

На Ваш взгляд, выделенный фрагмент - условное или уступительное предложение?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он бы ей всё равно не поверил, даже будь(если бы было) это правдой.-  придаточное условное. Здесь глагол повелительного наклонения в значении условного.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Людмила!!! : )