# Xотя vs даже если

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, для Вашего уха есть разница в этих предложениях?

> 1) *Он сделает ей выговор при всех, **хотя** она его сестра.*
>   2) *Он сделает ей выговор при всех, **даже если** она его сестра.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

**Разница есть.**

(1) Точно известно, что она его сестра.

(2) Он не знает наверняка, является ли некая ОНА его сестрой, но все равно сделает ей выговор.  Звучит довольно странно. Можно, конечно, вообразить такую ситуацию, но сначала хотелось бы узнать, что автор имел в виду.

P.S. Есть еще одна трактовка для (2). Рассказчику не известно, является ли она сестрой героя рассказа, но нет сомнений в том, что он (герой рассказа) сделает ей выговор.

Answer (score 4):

Для каждого из этих выражений естественна *своя* ситуация употребления (они не взаимозаменяемы). Например, возможны такие варианты контекста:

> Сегодня одна сотрудница опоздала на работу, а начальник у нас строгий,
> и можно предсказать, что будет. *Он сделает ей выговор при всех, хотя
> она его сестра.*
>
> Тренер нашей женской волейбольной сборной принципиален: если
> спортсменка допустит ошибку, *он сделает ей выговор при всех, даже если*
> *она его сестра.*

Comment: Два придаточных с союзом ЕСЛИ - это нормально?

Comment: Здесь нет двух отдельных "если". Сочетание "даже если" имеет свой законченный смысл, поэтому с уже имеющимся "если" не должно конфликтовать.

Comment: Речь не о смысле, а о стиле. С этой точки зрения возможен  повтор союза?

Answer (score 2):

Оба предложения относятся к разряду придаточных уступительных, но имеют **разное значение.**

1) **Реальная уступка** (она действительно его сестра): Он сделает ей выговор при всех, хотя она его сестра.

2) **Ирреальная (предположительная) уступка** (делается обобщение: речь идет о любой сотруднице, даже при наличии родственных отношений,  реально о существовании сестры ничего не известно, это только пример): Он сделает ей выговор при всех, даже если она его сестра (**даже если бы** она была его сестрой,   **будь** она **даже** его сестрой).

Союзный комплекс ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ заменяет союз ХОТЯ БЫ, имеющий значение ирреальной уступки (условное наклонение), что видно из следующих примеров: Мы не можем браться за любую работу, **хотя бы** она и казалась нам привлекательной. Мы не можем браться за любую работу, **даже если** она кажется нам привлекательной.

**Примеры с сочетанием "будь она даже"**

Монополия ― это, само собой, плохо, **будь она даже** естественной. По особенной ловкости и живости движений, **будь она даже** не совсем правильно хороша, вы тотчас отличите француженку, особенно парижанку. [Е. П. Ростопчина. Палаццо Форли (1854)]

Comment: спасибо большое! я правильно Вас понимаю: Он сделает ей выговор при всех, даже если она его сестра //даже если бы она была его сестрой - выбор наклонения выходит факультативный? может стоять и индикатив и сослагат. наклон. для выражения ир.уступки?

Comment: Да, всё верно Вы поняли. Мне на слух  оба варианта  кажутся идентичными, а  союзный комплекс ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ  упоминается в книге "Синтаксис современного русского языка". Дословно звучит так: подобные  отношения (ирреальной уступки) можно выразить и союзным комплексом ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ.

Comment: спасибо большое большое!